# Keyboard layout conflict with Ubuntu Budgie 22.04.1

Tags: 22.04, keyboard-layout, language-support, ubuntu-budgie

I upgraded Ubuntu Budgie from 20.04 to 22.04.1. Previously, I had configured in the settings dialog that I can switch between the keyboard layouts "DE" and "NO", which worked flawlessly with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. After the upgrade, this does not work anymore, but the keyboard settings in the system settings are set correctly.

In fact, the behavior is weird: The Tray symbol for the keyboard layout switches correctly between "DE" and "NO" by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. But the layouts actually switch between "DE" and "US".
The following is in `/etc/default/keyboard` (edited after comment):

```
XKBLAYOUT=de,no
BACKSPACE=guess
XKBMODEL=pc105
```

But `setxkbmap -query` gives me:

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     de,us
variant:    ,
```

which reflects the actual behavior when switching layouts. Using `setxkbmap "de,no"` yields

```
layout:     de,no
```

in the first place,

```
layout:     no,us
```

after pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> once and finally

```
layout:     de,us
```

after pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> twice. So the layouts which were previously configured get overriden somehow. `im-config -m` shows

```
default
default
none

none
```

if this is helpful in any regard. The output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` is

```
[('xkb', 'de'), ('xkb', 'no')]
```

and of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` (edited after comment)

```
@as []
```

I am somehow desperate right now since I cannot figure out what changes the settings in xkbmap such that my settings get overriden.
Has anyone an idea what could cause the problem?

Comment: That looks weird. Have you tried to reboot with that `/etc/default/keyboard` file?

Comment: Yes, I did several reboots. Even tried to manually install and use ibus (which was removed by the upgrade), but it did not help either and I removed it.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the output of these terminal commands: 1. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` 2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: thanks, I have added the information.

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data` (I have no idea if it makes a difference, but at least it won't hurt.)

Comment: Btw, try to drop `grp:win_space_toggle` from `/etc/default/keyboard`. Budgie is a GNOME like desktop, and `<Super>+Space` ought to be set via the GNOME mechanism.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson That will likely nail it - will be good to convert it to an answer when OP confirms.

Comment: I tried both hints, rebooted but it did not help - the problem still exists. What I observed: the `setxkbmap` output is somehow altered externally. Every time I press `Super+Space` it switches between `layout:     de,us` and `layout:     no,us`.

Comment: It struck me... What's the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` now? If `'grp:win_space_toggle'` is still included, then run `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` and try again.

Comment: Thank you for the hints - indeed, the `grp:win_space_toggle` was still in there. I executed the reset command and now it shows `@as []`, but unfortunately the problem still persists (even after reboot). The `setxkbmap -query` still shows `de,us` as languages.

Comment: Actually, I added Norwegian to my list of input sources (in standard Ubuntu), and `no` is not present for me either when I run `setxkbmap -query`. But I can effectively switch to Norwegian using `<Super>+Space`. Maybe also you can now?

Comment: Norwegian is set as the secondary input source (besides German) in the Ubuntu Budgie Preferences and when I use `<Super>+Space`, the Input indicator in the top bar switches between DE and NO. But what I actually get when I type something with my keyboard, is German layout when DE is indicated and US layout when NO is indicated (for example, the key which should give "ø" (ö-key on my kb) regarding the map in the system preferences yields ";").

Comment: Then I give up and would suggest that you submit a bug report: `ubuntu-bug budgie-desktop`

Comment: Ok, thank you very much so far!

Comment: Any progress?
I have absolutely the same problem on Ubuntu Budgie 22.04 with PL-UA layouts. The actual second layout is always US, even if it is indicated as UA or PL.

Comment: Unfortunately not - to be honest I did not find the time to open a bug report, since I did not use the keyboard switch in the last weeks. Maybe I will do it later. If you want to open one, you are welcome to take the information and insight we already obtained in this thread.